# Type "submit" doing onclick before form "action"

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this form to select a csv file then upload it to mysql server:

```
<form class="ui input" enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "POST" action="trend_upload_csv.php" role = "form">
   <input type = "file" name ="file" id="file" size = "150">
   <input id="myBtn"  class="ui small red button" type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default"  name ="submit"  onclick = "myFunction();" value = "Upload CSV"  disabled  /> 
</form>
```

Then a function to enable the upload button if there is a file selected, then disable the upload button once it was clicked then change the text of button to "uploading"

```
<script>
   function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
     document.getElementById("myBtn").value="Uploading";
   }

   $(document).ready(
   function(){
      $('input:file').change(
      function(){
          if ($(this).val()) {
             $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
          } 
      });
  });
</script>
```

My problem is it doesn't do the action to my php code and this results to disabling my upload button and changing text to "uploading" and nothing happens. How can I do the action before the onclick?

Comment: "_How can I do the action before the onclick?_" You can't, this is the intrinsic firing order of the events. Also, if the submission would take a place before onclick, a new page loading would prevent the onclick to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

essentially you told the javascript that when I click on the button just change the button properties. not to upload the file. and the jquery code you have written is redundant as well.

you can do something like this in order to submit the form on click,

```
<script>
   function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
     document.getElementById("myBtn").value="Uploading";
     document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
   }
</script>
```

**(don't forget to add an id attribute to form)**

Comment: i tried your solution but still the same, it doesn't do the action, I did put an id to my form

Comment: this worked for me, but I deleted the button.disabled = true, I think this is the cause why it doesn't do the post